# Error header("Location) en Inicio de Sesion PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login

estoy creando un inicio de sesion con php y mysql, pero a la hora de redireccionar, los header no funcionan y hacen que se detenga el codigo, una cosa asi. No entiendo el motivo, pero antes no me pasaba. Solo ahora me pasa. Esta creado con sesiones para la validacion de usuarios y todo lo de un login. Cuando saco el header del codigo, funciona perfecto pero cuando lo pongo empieza a funcionar mal.

Hola, estoy creando un inicio de sesion con php y mysql, pero a la hora de redireccionar, los header no funcionan y hacen que se detenga el codigo, una cosa asi. No entiendo el motivo, pero antes no me pasaba. Solo ahora me pasa. Esta creado con sesiones para la validacion de usuarios y todo lo de un login. Cuando saco el header del codigo, funciona perfecto pero cuando lo pongo empieza a funcionar mal.

```
<?php session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['user_nombre_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['user_codigo_identificacion'])) {

    session_regenerate_id();

        header("Location: ../usuario/");

        exit();

}elseif (isset($_SESSION['nombre_empresa']) && isset($_SESSION['codigo_identificacion_comercio'])) {

    session_regenerate_id();

        header("Location: ../panel/");

    exit();

}

$error_login = '';


if (isset($_POST['validador-acceso'])) {

//Validamos si se enviaron los datos correctamente

    if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    //Validamos si el campo ingresado esta vacio o no

        if (empty($_POST['usuario']) && empty($_POST['password'])) {

            //Colocamos el mensaje de error

                $error_login = 'Los datos ingresados no pueden estar vacios';

        }else{

            //Limpiamos los datos recibidos

        require_once '../../assets/0/config.php';

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

                $usuario_cross = $_POST['usuario'];

                $usuario_mysql = $mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario_cross);

                $usuario_trim = trim($usuario_mysql);

                $usuario_slc = htmlentities($usuario_trim);

                $usuario_usuario = htmlspecialchars($usuario_slc);

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

                $password_cross = $_POST['password'];

                $password_mysql = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password_cross);

                $password_trim = trim($password_mysql);

                $password_slc = htmlentities($password_trim);

                $password_password = htmlspecialchars($password_slc);

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

            //Encriptamos las claves de acceso

                $usuario_hash = hash('sha512', $usuario_usuario);

                $password_hash = hash('sha512', $password_password);


                $vld_cmc = $mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM comercios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password");

                $vld_cmc->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                $vld_cmc->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

                $vld_cmc->execute();

                $registros_obtenidos_comercios = $vld_cmc->fetchColumn();

                    switch ($registros_obtenidos_comercios) {

                        case 0:

                                $error_login = 'Tu usuario y/o clave no coinciden con nuestros registros. Intentalo de nuevo';

                        break;

                        case 1:

                                //Empezamos la creacion de sesiones e insercion de ingreso a la db

                                $slct_dt_comercio = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM comercios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password");

                                $slct_dt_comercio->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                                $slct_dt_comercio->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

                                $slct_dt_comercio->execute();

                                while ($dt_cmc = $slct_dt_comercio->fetch()){

                                    $nombre_empresa_usuario_comercio = $dt_cmc['nombre_empresa'];

                                    $nombre_empresa_usuario_con_comercio = $dt_cmc['nombre_empresa_con'];

                                    $codigo_identificacion_usuario_comercio = $dt_cmc['codigo_identificacion'];

                                }


                                    $_SESSION['nombre_empresa'] = $nombre_empresa_usuario_comercio;

                                    $_SESSION['codigo_identificacion_comercio'] = $codigo_identificacion_usuario_comercio;

                                    $_SESSION['confirm_access'] = 'true';

                                header("Location: ../panel/");

                            exit();



                        break;

                    }


        } //Termina Empty

    } //Termina validador datos recibidos POST

} //Termina validador acceso Boton?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los header se mandan una vez que se llega al controlador, eso significa que en el ultimo header con el que quieres redireccionar te va a mandar el error `Header have already been sent` en el ultimo caso te recomiendo que lo hagas con JS `echo '<script>window.location.href = "URL";</script>'` con eso deberia de funcionar.

Comment: Gracias! Lo Probaré